# Change var globaly in swift

Tags: swift, global, var

I want to change the value of a var in a swift file that i create:

```
class functions {

    var DataSent = "Sensor"

    func setValue (DataSent: String) {
      self.DataSent =  DataSent
    }

    func getValue () -> String {
        return self.DataSent
    }


}
```

when i call setValue the DataSent doesn't change what can i do?

i call it like that:

```
functions().setValue(stringData)
```

and then i call it to another class with getValue

Comment: You're `init`'ing a new `functions` every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `functions` each time you call `functions()`. It's best to use a `struct` with `static` functions and static variables in situations like this.

```
struct functions {

    static var DataSent = "Sensor"

    static func setValue (DataSent: String) {
      self.DataSent =  DataSent
    }

    static func getValue () -> String {
        return self.DataSent
    }
}

print(functions.DataSent)
functions.setValue(DataSent: "Blaah")
print(functions.DataSent)
```

Comment: can i use it everywhere in my project?

Comment: Even better – define this as a caseless `enum`. That way you can't accidently create an instance, you just get a namespace for your static functions/properties. Although that being said, you should always be reluctant in using mutable global state.